# Cannot run docker commands through Jenkin's Blue Ocean: ERRO[0000] No subuid ranges found for user “jenkins” in /etc/subuid

Tags: docker, jenkins, rhel, jenkins-blueocean

Setup my first pipeline using Jenkin's Ocean Blue on a EC2 RHEL 8 instance and when attempting to run docker commands (such as as docker pull maven:3.6.2-jdk-14) as the jenkins user the following error is always returned No subuid ranges found for user "jenkins" in /etc/subuid

From a bit of research it seems I need to add the jenkins user to /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid but I'm unsure how to do this or what to add. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are more likely to get help for issues like this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 5):

What version of docker are you using? Is it really `docker` or `podman`? As far as I know, `podman` is the default container engine on RHEL 8. It sounds like you are using that, because the error mentions subuid, and that's only used when running as non-root.

The [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/podman#Rootless_mode) pretty much tells you what to do:

```
Or just add the content manually.

$ echo USERNAME:10000:65536 >> /etc/subuid
$ echo USERNAME:10000:65536 >> /etc/subgid
```

So just replace `USERNAME` with `jenkins` and you should be good to go. Run the following as root:

```
echo jenkins:10000:65536 >> /etc/subuid
echo jenkins:10000:65536 >> /etc/subgid
```